# ionic file upload with php logs out error file undefined

Tags: php, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to upload files to a remote server with php and when i upload i get this error `Undefined index: file`

PHP

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "Upload and move success";
} else {
echo $target_path;
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

TS

```
    var options1 = {
            fileKey: 'file',
            fileName: 'name.jpg',
            headers: {}
          }

            fileTransfer.upload(fileUri, this.global.baseUrl+'upload_photo_report.php', options1)
            .then((data) => {
              this.img = data.response
}
```

Can anyone help me out on how to make the file upload work as it should. Thanks

Comment: how you initialize fileTransfer ?

Comment: the fileUri also ? can you show more code